# gstreamer sample documentation code not running

Tags: c, gstreamer, glib, lvalue

Trying to compile and run a sample appsrc code after having successfully executed several tutorials. This is a documentation code, supposed it to run but ...

The command used to compile

```
gcc appGuideAppSrc.c -o appGuide `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10 gstreamer-app-0.10`
```

Got the following error after

```
appGuideAppSrc.c: In function ‘cb_need_data’:  
appGuideAppSrc.c:14:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]  
appGuideAppSrc.c:18:25: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Ok, the warning is fine but the line where it throws error is which seems to be ok

```
   GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = timestamp;
```

Based on answer below from @Michal, changed it to TIMESTAMP and got the following error

```
(appGuide:11043): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(appGuide:11043): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_add_many: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element_1)' failed  

(appGuide:11043): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_link_many: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element_1)' failed  

(appGuide:11043): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed  

(appGuide:11043): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance  

(appGuide:11043): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion  `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Any inputs ?

References:
The [whole appsrc sample code](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-data-spoof.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to compile a gstreamer-1.0 example with an older version of gstreamer: 0.10.

`GST_BUFFER_PTS` and `GST_BUFFER_DTS` were introduced in gstreamer-0.11 and replaced `GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP` available up to gstreamer-0.10.

Either use a newer gstreamer version or change `GST_BUFFER_PTS` to `GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Why do you say that "the warning is fine"? I'd rather recommend the opposite: compile your code with -Wall

Comment: I said warning is fine (Like I am a programmer, don't care about warning) types. Lets focus on error. :)

Comment: I guess that this time the line with `appsrc = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "source");` failed. Make sure that you have appsrc plugin (launch `gst-inspect-0.10 appsrc`). Running your program with environment variable `GST_DEBUG` set to e.g. `3` could also be helpful.

Comment: No need, your answer relating to 0.10 and 1.0 was correct.