# GStreamer SDK GUI Toolkit tutorial broken Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, gstreamer

I am attempting to compile and run the GStreamer ["GUI toolkit integration" tutorial](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+5%3A+GUI+toolkit+integration)  out of the box on Mac OS X 10.9 & Xcode 5.1.1. I am running GStreamer 0.10, the version that comes from their download page. The previous examples compiled and ran with no problem, but as soon as GTK+ and Pango get involved, I get these runtime errors.

```
(process:2634): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(Tutorial 5:2634): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_fontset_foreach: assertion `PANGO_IS_FONTSET (fontset)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_fontset_foreach: assertion `PANGO_IS_FONTSET (fontset)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_fontset_foreach: assertion `PANGO_IS_FONTSET (fontset)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_fontset_foreach: assertion `PANGO_IS_FONTSET (fontset)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderCoreText', script='common'

(Tutorial 5:2634): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): Pango-WARNING **: couldn't load font ".Lucida Grande UI Not-Rotated 12", modified variant/weight/stretch as fallback, expect ugly output.

(Tutorial 5:2634): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Tutorial 5:2634): Pango-ERROR **: Could not load fallback font, bailing out.
```

Could it possibly a version issue? Running newer examples with an older version of GStreamer, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18429154/3957976)?

Thanks in advance for the help. Let me know if I am not being specific enough.